# Windows Phone 7: How to play the Recording Files in Media Player?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, audio-recording, microphone

I completed the Recording using the Microphone with the help of

> [Audio Recording and PlayBack](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Audio_recording_and_playback_options_in_Windows_Phone)

I Already played that Recorded sound with help of this link also in application.

But i want to play that Recorded Audio sound into Our Windows phone's Media Player.

Please Anybody suggest me that how can i play the Recorded Sound in windows phone Media player.

Comment: Please Give me the Answer. I am waiting

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use the built in Media Player try this-

[Media Player Task from `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks Namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.mediaplayerlauncher%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

To use custom interface please refer to the Media player class defined in the

[Media Player from `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media Namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.aspx)

Comment: thanks for reply.
I already know it.
But actually, that recorded sound is in "dynamicsoundeffectinstance" format.
so i want to play this file format in media player.
There is the method for dynamicsoundeffectinstance is play(). this will actually plays the recorded sound. but i want to play this in media player.